# Rails: Select records from database with same foreign keys as current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

my app has three tables: Users, Organizations and UserOrganizations. The last table holds user_id and organization_id. So every user can have many organizations.

What I want to do now is to select all users that have the same organization_id's in the user_organization table than the current user.

So e. g. if the current user belongs to organizations with ids 3, 6 and 8 I want to select all users that belong to the same organizations.

The question may be stupid and simple but I'm stuck now with that for hours. :-/

Thx

**user.rb**

```
has_many :user_organizations
has_many :organizations, through: :user_organizations
```

**organization.rb**

```
has_many :user_organizations
has_many :users, through: :user_organizations
```

**user_organization.rb**

```
belongs_to :organization
belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run through the join table like

`UserOrganization.includes(:user)
  .where(organization: current_user.organizations)
  .map(&:user)`

The nice thing here is that by adding `includes` you're hinting to ActiveRecord that you're going to need the user and it makes the query more efficient.  It should work without the `includes` as long as your join table model has the `belongs_to` (which yours does).  But without the `includes`, if you `map(&:user)` it'll make N more queries to grab user data (where N is the number of users that match) instead of using a database join to grab that data with the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user_organizations = current_user.organizations
users_from_same_organization = User.where(organizations: user_organizations)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.